# Consumir Web API y mandar una estructura

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

soy nuevo con las Web API necesito consumir una web API la cual recibe como parametro una estructura la cual es la siguiente:

```
public struct TFingers
        {            
            public byte[] CMeniqueIzq;
            public byte[] CAnularIzq;
            public byte[] CMedioIzq;
            public byte[] CIndiceIzq;
            public byte[] CPulgar;
            public byte[] CMeniqueDer;
            public byte[] CAnularDer;
            public byte[] CMedioDer;
            public byte[] CIndiceDer;
            public byte[] CPulgarDer;
        }
```

Ya ingrese el contenido de cada variable dentro de la estructura, ahora la pregunta seria como puedo enviarle esta estructura a la Web API ?? 
Tengo este codigo pero me arroja error 404

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62773/");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Huellas/" + Fingers);

            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, Gracias!

Comment: estas seguro que se consume como GET ? porque cuando hay una estructura se suele enviar como post en el content

Comment: si consumes la webapi desde PostMan resuelve correctamente ? si es ais como envias los datos

Comment: 404 normalmente significa que la URL está mal, si ingresas "http://localhost:62773/api/Huellas" en la barra del navegador, ¿también sale 404?

Comment: esta claro que para que funcione `localhost:62773` se debe configurar el sitio en el IIS, o asegurarse que el Visual Studio este ejecutando para que inicie el IIS Express

Comment: Si consume como GET, pero creo que tendré que probar con POST para ver si consume correctamente de esta forma

En PostMan si resuelve pero no puedo crear la estructura ahí mismo

Cuando coloco solo la URL  "localhost:62773/api/Huellas" me regresa un Json como "null"

Se publica cuando ejecutas la web API dentro de Visual Studio ya que ejecuta el IIS Express y así el servicio es expuesto

Comment: el GET no te va a dejar enviar un json como parte del body, solo podras hacer si usas POST o PUT, pruebalo en el postman a ver como responde, una vez que en postman resuelvas bien como deebs invocar al webapi entonces sera mas simple pasar esa funcionalidad a codigo

Comment: Les agradezco muchos sus comentarios, voy a cambiar a POST, gracias!